# C: trouble using a #define value in a function prototype, or inside a structure declaration

Tags: c, struct, function-prototypes

I have trouble using defined values in different files. I have a file named "flexsea.h" that contains definitions for the whole project (such as #define COMM_STR_BUF_LEN 48). Most of the files in my project include flexsea.h and I can use COMM_STR_BUF_LEN. Two situations are causing me trouble.

First part of flexsea.h:

```
//****************************************************************************
// flexsea: Master file for the FlexSEA stack.
//****************************************************************************

#ifndef INC_FLEXSEA_H_
#define INC_FLEXSEA_H_

//****************************************************************************
// Include(s)
//****************************************************************************

#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdarg.h>

//All the FlexSEA stack includes:
#include "flexsea_buffers.h"
#include "flexsea_comm.h"
#include "flexsea_payload.h"
#include "flexsea_rx_cmd.h"
#include "flexsea_tx_cmd.h"
#include "flexsea_cmd_comm.h"
#include "flexsea_cmd_control.h"
#include "flexsea_cmd_data.h"
#include "flexsea_cmd_external.h"
#include "flexsea_cmd_sensors.h"
#include "flexsea_cmd_system.h"
#include "flexsea_cmd_user.h"

//****************************************************************************
// Prototype(s):
//****************************************************************************

unsigned int flexsea_error(unsigned int err_code);
void uint32_to_bytes(uint32_t x, uint8_t *b0, uint8_t *b1, uint8_t *b2, uint8_t *b3);
void uint16_to_bytes(uint32_t x, uint8_t *b0, uint8_t *b1);
void fill_uint8_buf(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t len, uint8_t filler);

//****************************************************************************
// Definition(s):
//****************************************************************************

//Buffers and packets:
#define RX_BUF_LEN                      64      //Reception buffer (flexsea_comm)
#define PAYLOAD_BUF_LEN                 24      //Number of bytes in a payload string
#define PAYLOAD_BYTES                   (PAYLOAD_BUF_LEN - 4)
#define COMM_STR_BUF_LEN                48      //Number of bytes in a comm. string
#define PACKAGED_PAYLOAD_LEN            48      //Temporary
#define PAYLOAD_BUFFERS                 4       //Max # of payload strings we expect to find
```

**First situation:** using COMM_STR_BUF_LEN  in a structure

```
#ifndef INC_FX_COMM_H
#define INC_FX_COMM_H

//****************************************************************************
// Include(s)
//****************************************************************************

#include "flexsea.h"

//****************************************************************************
// Local variable(s)
//****************************************************************************

//****************************************************************************
// Structure(s):
//****************************************************************************

struct sc_data_s
{
     uint8_t flag;                              //1 when new data ready to be transmitted
     uint8_t str[48];                         //Data to be transmitted     //ToDo Should be COMM_STR_BUF_LEN!
     uint8_t length;                              //Number of bytes to be sent
     uint8_t cmd;                              //What's the command? (used to know if we will get an answer)
     uint8_t listen;                              //1 when we expect an answer
};

...
#endif
```

*str[48]* should be *str[COMM_STR_BUF_LEN]* but GCC tells me that it's un declared. If I don't use it in the struct I can #define TEST COMM_STR_BUF_LEN and it compiles file.

Example of a code that compiles:

```
struct sc_data_s
{
     uint8_t flag;
     uint8_t str[48];
     uint8_t length;
     uint8_t cmd;
     uint8_t listen;
};
```

This is also fine:

```
#define LEN 48
struct sc_data_s
{
     uint8_t flag;
     uint8_t str[LEN];
     uint8_t length;
     uint8_t cmd;
     uint8_t listen;
};
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
struct sc_data_s
{
     uint8_t flag;
     uint8_t str[COMM_STR_BUF_LEN];
     uint8_t length;
     uint8_t cmd;
     uint8_t listen;
};
```

Error message:
    *./inc/../../common/inc/flexsea_comm.h:30:14: error: 'COMM_STR_BUF_LEN' undeclared here (not in a function)*

**Second situation:** using COMM_STR_BUF_LEN in a prototype

In a different file I had this prototype in my header:

```
void clear_rx_command(uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint8_t rx_cmd[][PACKAGED_PAYLOAD_LEN]);
```

Couldn't compile with PACKAGED_PAYLOAD_LEN, had to hardcode a value. For that use case I moved the prototype to the .c because it's a private function, but I'd like to know how to do that for next time.

My two issues are similar so I suspect a fundamental misunderstanding. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Jeff

Comment: If all you did with `#define TEST COMM_STR_BUF_LEN` was write that one line, that won't tell you anything about whether `COMM_STR_BUF_LEN` is defined; you'd have to go on to use `TEST` in actual code for that.

Comment: Can you post relevant piece of `flexsea.h`?

Comment: I edited the first post to include a piece of flexsea.h and better examples of what I tried. Thanks!

Comment: That's weird. Can you check it is defined by `#ifdef....#warning` or similar?

Comment: #ifdef COMM_STR_BUF_LEN
#warning "Defined!"
#endif 

No warning... so it's not defined in that file... now I have to figure out why.

Comment: In the same fashion try to check whether the right "flexsea.h" is included.

Comment: You have to pick one of the two options of having `flexsea.h` include everything, and having everything include `flexsea.h` .   I'd suggest having one header which is meant to be included by other headers and contains common typedefs and defines and no includes;  and the "include-all" header (if you even need one) is something that should only be included by .c files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing that the guard macro `INC_FX_COMM_H` indicates that the code following is in file `flexsea_comm.h`, note that that header is included by `flexsea.h`, above the point where the `COMM_STR_BUF_LEN` macro is defined.  As a result, `flexsea_comm.h` will always be processed before that macro is defined unless it is `#include`d separately, before `flexsea.h`.

The same likely applies to your function prototype, supposing that it also appears in one of the headers included by `flexsea.h`.

The easiest and least disruptive solution would probably be to move the macro definitions to the *top* of `flexsea.h`, right after the guard macro.

Comment: Alternatively, since it seems that this macro is relevant to comms, it should be `#define`d in flexsea_comm.h instead of flexsea.h .

Comment: @MattMcNabb, possibly so.  Or since it appears the various headers are not actually capable of being used independently, perhaps it would be better to merge them all into one.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger, that was my problem. I moved all the flexsea includes at the bottom of flexsea.h and everything works.